# How to Instantiate a Custom EventArgs Class that has no Accessible Constructor?

Tags: c#, eventargs

I have a problem; I'm using an external library where one particular event has its own custom eventargs; with no constructor. If I want to throw my own event using these eventargs, how can I?

I'll give more detail if asked, but I'm not sure what exactly I should be giving. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers suggest some ways (or hacks) how you could do that.

However, I'd say that if the author of the library didn't give you any way to create a new instance of their custom `EventArgs` class, then you shouldn't be doing that. If you want to create your own event, then you should define a new `delegate` and new `EventArgs` type (even if you were duplicating the class that is already defined in the library).

There are good reasons for this:

- The library may change and the custom `EventArgs` type they provide may no longer fit your needs.
- The library may need to pass some special object or special ID to their `EventArgs`, so you may not be able to create the instance correctly.

Since you can only trigger an event from a class where it is defined, you're probably defining a new event in the class (using the `event` keyword), so there is no real reason why you couldn't declare your own delegate. Or could you provide more details on how are you triggering the event?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new type that inherits from that EventArgs class and use that.  Most likely the existing EventArgs type is `abstract` so you can create a new type that will inherit from it and C#'s polymorphic support will allow you to pass your new type to all methods that expect an instance of the base type.

Comment: Ah, I've already tried this. First of all; the members I wanted to set using my inherited class's constructor were private to the parent class, and secondly it wouldn't allow me to create a constructor in my inherited class.

Also, the custom class isn't abstract I think, as I'm using instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Reflector to find out how the external library instantiates it.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the designers of the library made the constructor internal to prevent you doing exactly what you're trying to do - for better or for worse. So anything you do will be a hack.

You could use Reflection to create an instance the class - see `Activator.CreateInstance`.

An even bigger hack might be to re-use an instance of the args object that you received and stored, but that's dangerous - who knows what internal data it might contain.

Comment: That's assuming that the designers of the library knew what they were doing.  I've seen my fair share that didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to obtain an instance of the class using `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices`. Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

...

```
Foo foo = (Foo)FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject(typeof(Foo));
```